# How can kubectl acces k8s cluster in another server

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, telepresence

I tried to create a k8s cluster in my MacBook Pro M1, but fail because of M1. So I want to create the k8s in another windows and the MacBook will connect to the cluster with kubectl and telepresenc.

1. create a k8s cluster in the ubuntu server 20.04 which is in the vmware of windows 10.
2. in my MacBook, use kubectl and telepresence to access the k8s cluster.

[image]

I use microk8s to manage the k8s.

The problem is when I access k8s in windows, I fail and was tell that I can only access the k8s through 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.23.130 but not 192.168.10.11.

How can I solve the problem or achive this structure with another method.

Comment: How did you set up the cluster (your config file)? Did you use Ingress, NodePort, LoadBalanser? Which errors did you see at the command line? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: how is vmware network configuration https://superuser.com/a/227508/126098